# Render P2P metabox per taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, plugin-posts-to-posts

I would like to display a Posts to Posts connection registration metabox for each term in a custom taxonomy. The post connection candidates will be split across the metaboxes depending on their term.

Each post only has one term associated, so there is no risk of duplicate candidates.

For example, given these posts and terms:

- "Philadelphia" with term "City"
- "Pittsburgh" with term "City"
- "Pennsylvania" with term "State"
- "USA" with term "Country"

There would be three metaboxes, with each post contained within:

- Cities

  - Philadelphia
  - Pittsburgh
- States

  - Pennsylvania
- Countries

  - USA

How might this be accomplished?